# Macro in Excel 2016 not moving both DUPLICATED rows but only 1 of the duplicate rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working in Excel 2016, and I have a macro where I'm trying to remove ALL duplicated rows from the main worksheet and move them to the Duplicates worksheet starting at A3 and what is happening is that in the Duplicates worksheet is that it is cutting only 1 of the rows and NOT both rows from the Main worksheet.  Any help/direction as to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is my macro code:

```
Sub CutDuplicates()
    Dim Rng As Range, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Rng = Range("A3:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    For i = Rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, Cells(i, "A")) > 1 Then
          lr = Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
          Rows(i).EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Sheets("Duplicates").Range("A" & lr)
          Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Once the duplicate row has been cut, then the result of `CountIf` will not be greater than 1. I'd use `Range.AutoFilter` here.

Comment: Or you could flip the logic: if the result of the `CountIf` *equals* 1, then move that row to a new sheet... you'll end up with the list of rows that have no duplicates on the new sheet.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, your time and help were appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note there's a subtle bug in your posted code: `Rng` starts in Row#3, but in your loop `i` is relative to `Rng`, not the whole sheet, so (eg) when `i=1` that's Row#3 on the sheet, not Row#1.

Instead of cutting as you go, you can collect the rows to be cut and then move them:

```vb
Sub CutDuplicates()
    
    Dim Rng As Range, i As Long, col As New Collection, ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'always qualify all ranges with a worksheet object...
    Set Rng = ws.Range("A3:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    'collect all duplicate rows
    For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, Rng.Rows(i).Value) > 1 Then
          col.Add i 'store row# in collection
        End If
    Next i
    
    'now cut the duplicates to the other sheet
    Set c = Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    For i = col.Count To 1 Step -1 'step backwards through the rows
        Rng.Rows(col(i)).EntireRow.Cut Destination:=c
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'next paste destination
        Rng.Rows(col(i)).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim!!  Appreciate your time and help.  Made a lot of sense.